# Multiple boxplots with ggplot2 in the same layer from a melted data frame with a condition

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, melt

I have some data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4wrqfcvr0tngimt/data.txt) [in a .txt file] which I read into a data frame,

```
mydf <- read.table("data.txt", header=T,sep="\t")
```

I melt this data frame next using the following piece of code,

```
df_mlt <-melt(mydf, id=names(mydf)[1], variable = "cols")
```

Now I would like to plot this data as a boxplot displaying only values of `x>0` , so for this I use the following code,

```
plt_bx <-   ggplot(df_mlt, aes(x=ID1,y=value>0, color=cols))+geom_boxplot()
```

But the resulting plot looks like the following,

[image: Output of the boxplot]

However what I need is to only display positive values of x as individual box plots in the same plot layer. Could someone please suggest what I need to change in the above code to get the proper output, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I improved my answer, the outline of the boxplot would display different colors if color in the aes is assigned as a factor of the id from the melted data frame. i.e., `geom_boxplot(aes(color=factor(ID1)))`

The following code results in a plot as below,

```
plt <- ggplot(subset(df_mlt, value > 0), aes(x=ID1,y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(color=factor(ID1))) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=14), legend.title=element_text(size=14))+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20)) +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold")) +
  labs(x = "x", y = "y",colour="legend" ) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "rl") +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  guides(title.hjust=0.5) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,1,0,0),"mm")) 
plt
```

[image: Output plot]

Answer (score 2):

```
plt_bx <- ggplot(subset(df_mlt, value > 0), aes(x=ID1,y=value, color=cols)) + geom_boxplot()
```

You need to subset your data frame to remove the undesirable values.  Right now you're plotting `value > 0`, which is either TRUE or FALSE, instead of the boxplot of only the values that are greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Using the condition in the subset removes the negative values. I would like to display separate boxplots for each of the x variable ID's

Comment: @Amm, try adding `group=ID1` to the `aes`, but without your data is hard to be more specific.  If you post the `dput` of a representative section of your data I can give you the exact command.

Comment: I have the data as a .csv file in the link in my question

Comment: @Amm, I'd prefer a `dput`.  My Excel thinks your file is suspect.

Comment: I dont know why your Excel think that data file is suspect. Thanks for your suggestion this seems to work, `plt_bx <- ggplot(subset(df_mlt, value > 0), aes(x=ID1,group=ID1,y=value, color=cols)) + geom_boxplot() +scale_y_log10()` . However the aes color in the boxplot does not appear to be applied though

Comment: @Amm, try `color=ID1`, unless you want a specific color, in which case it gets more complicated.  If this works you also don't need `group`.

Comment: I tried `color=ID1` it displays the boxplot correctly but with one single gradient of colors for the outline of the boxplot. What I wanted to display was different colors though something like variable, but since the variable aes is defined already in the melted data frame line which is `cols` I use this for color such as `color = cols` which in principle should work well I presume?

Comment: @Amm I'm not sure I understand, do you want each boxplot to have multiple colors, or are all the values of `cols` for any single `ID1` value the same color you want the boxplot to be?

Comment: What I mean is to obtain different colors for the outline of each individual boxplot so calling the aes `color=cols` should work like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335625/getting-the-y-axis-intercept-and-slope-from-a-linear-regression-of-multiple-data  .But using group I think overrides the color aes definition

Comment: @Amm, as I noted earlier, if you are using `color=cols`, and `cols` doesn't specify an actual color, but just a group, and the groups in `cols` are the same as the groups in `ID1`, then you don't need `group`, you can just use `color=cols`.  If the conditions described here are not met, then you can't use `cols` to color the boxplots, at least not through `aes`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, the plot now seems to be much better, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @BrodieG suggestions, the following piece of code yields a plot as below,

```
plt_bx <- ggplot(subset(df_mlt, value > 0), aes(x=ID1,y=value,group=ID1)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(color=ID1),outlier.colour="orangered", outlier.size=3) +
  scale_y_log10(labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=14), legend.title=element_text(size=14))+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=26)) +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=22,face="bold")) +
  labs(x = "x", y = "y", colour="Values") +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "rl")
plt_bx
```

[image]